# Minimum and maximum length in a regular expression

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I'm using the following regular expression to validate emails:

```
^\w+([-.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

Now I want to modify this regular expression to validate the email length using {5,100}. How can I do that?

Comment: You must always specify what language you are using your regex from. It's even written in the tag.

Comment: Pretty please, don't pollute the Internet with yet another broken email address "validator".  Please read and understand http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for a start.

Comment: As an additional note to what @tripleee wrote, please don't use the last one. It's based on a "closed" list of TLD, but now anyone rich enough can buy a TLD. Someone could even buy a `nospam` TLD :-)

Comment: Yes, seconded.  It cautions against using the proposed regex blindly, but perhaps it should be clearer about "don't do this at home, at all".

Comment: Xanatos: tags are ok now. triplee: the expression fits my needs, read a manual about "over compensating my penis size on the internet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.{5,100}$)\w+([-.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

I'm using the zero-width lookahead. It won't consume characters, so you can then recheck them with your expression.

Comment: Thank you for the lookaround syntax. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. This is a relatively weak expression and matches even *user@server.com.net.org*. Email regexes were already discussed in many other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/557306).

Checking for the length of a string can generally be done within the language/tool you're using. This might be even faster in some cases. As an example (in Perl):

```
my $len = length $str;
if ($len < 5 || $len > 100) {
    # Something is wrong
}
```

Comment: I want to validade the len in the expression itself. Thx.